# how to detect ouliers in audio dataset?

Tags: data-preprocessing

I'm currently working on an audio classification project using CNNs. The problem is I'm having trouble training my CNN. I doubt if there are outliers in my dataset but I don't know how to detect outliers in an **audio dataset**. I've searched google and found nothing helpful.

Comment: Tell us what you have found so far and why it's not helpful. Explain also exactly what you're looking for.

Comment: @nbro almost everything I found on google was about finding outliers in tabular data, therefore, they're not applicable to audio or any kind of time series data.

Answer (score 1):

A first think what comes to mind is to train an autoencoder, then identify abnormal data by these heuristics:

- Is the reconstruction error large, for example remove the top 5% of the data?
- Are the codes (outputs of the encoder) within a densely populated region, or are they outliers? You could calculate the distance to Nth nearest neighbor.

Comment: Interesting idea, do you know any articles that has done that on audio or any kind of time series data?

Comment: I haven't read any of these papers, but I found plenty from Google Scolar by searching for "autoencoder outlier detection".